# PSObject -Property with conditions

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, psobject

I would like to put conditions in this part of my code:

```
$objInfos = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    Dossier = [string]"$($logs[0])"
                    "Taille totale" = [double]$logs[1]
                    "Categorie recherchee" = [double]$logs[2]
                    "Pourcentage" = [double]$logs[3]
                    "Date de dernier acces" = [DateTime]"$($logs[5])"
}
```

I'd need every case to have conditions, like that:

```
$objInfos = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    if ($test -eq 1){
                        Dossier = [string]"$($logs[0])"
                    }
                    "Taille totale" = [double]$logs[1]
                    "Categorie recherchee" = [double]$logs[2]
                    "Pourcentage" = [double]$logs[3]
                    "Date de dernier acces" = [DateTime]"$($logs[5])"
}
```

I tried this way and it didn't work

> Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.

Does someone know how to do please?

Comment: You can use `Add-Member` to add the property if it is required. I see you have asked a number of questions here recently and not yet accepted any answers, though there have been some good ones. Please either do so, or leave a comment to the authors such that they can make amendments if required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create `Hashtable` in separate statement, fill it with values, and then pass it to `New-Object` cmdlet.

```
$Hashtable = @{}
if ($test -eq 1){
    $Hashtable.Add('Dossier', [string]"$($logs[0])")
}
$Hashtable.Add("Taille totale", [double]$logs[1])
$Hashtable.Add("Categorie recherchee", [double]$logs[2])
$Hashtable.Add("Pourcentage", [double]$logs[3])
$Hashtable.Add("Date de dernier acces", [DateTime]"$($logs[5])")
$objInfos = New-Object PSObject -Property $Hashtable
```

If you want to have properties in the same order as elements added to `Hashtable`, then you need to use `OrderedDictionary` instead of `Hashtable`:

```
$Hashtable = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
```

Comment: I have a new problem now, before the conditions were here i used this :
`$tab | select Dossier,"Taille Totale","Categorie recherchee", "Pourcentage", "Date de dernier acces" | Sort-Object "Pourcentage" -descending | format-table -autosize | out-string -width 4000 | out-file -append O:\******\******\parcoursArborescence\bilanAnalyse.txt` How can i do to make him write only the right ones ?

Comment: I dont see what you are suggesting me to do (sorry i feel ridiculous). Problem is, i need to select these but i dont know how, is it possible to write those conditions again, to put results in a variable and then make a select which regroups everything ? I'm kind of lost, i dont know how to do

Comment: @Kikopu I am not sure what your problem is. If `$tab` is objects you just create, then I does not see, why do you need `select` command in your pipeline. Simply remove it: `$tab | Sort-Object ...`. If that does not help, then you should show the current output, the output you want to get and how them different.

Comment: ..... Okay i was lost somehow, but that was obvious.... So yeah, it fixes the "problem". I used the select command for a problem I had before, so by reading it again, i thought i needed it, but no. Thanks a lot !

Comment: ... Still have a question, sorry... Without a select command, Is there a way to decide the order of the columns ? If I want the tab to be written the same way the hashtable is filled ?

Comment: @Kikopu PowerShell version?

Comment: @Kikopu Please do not move the target. If you have a new question: post a new question.

Comment: PowerShell 2. Well then, I will post this question, sorry

Answer (score 3):

You can conditonally add entries to the property hashtable as [@PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34039999/1630171) suggested:

```
$props = @{
  'Taille totale'         = [double]$logs[1]
  'Categorie recherchee'  = [double]$logs[2]
  'Pourcentage'           = [double]$logs[3]
  'Date de dernier acces' = [DateTime]$logs[5]
}

if ($test -eq 1) {
  $props['Dossier'] = "$($logs[0])"
}

$objInfos = New-Object PSObject -Property $props
```

You can use `Add-Member` as @arco444 suggested in the comments to your question:

```
$objInfos = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
  'Taille totale'         = [double]$logs[1]
  'Categorie recherchee'  = [double]$logs[2]
  'Pourcentage'           = [double]$logs[3]
  'Date de dernier acces' = [DateTime]$logs[5]
}

if ($test -eq 1) {
  $objInfos | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name 'Dossier' -Value "$($logs[0])"
}
```

Or you can add the property regardless, but set its value depending on the result of your check:

```
$objInfos = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
  'Dossier'               = if ($test -eq 1) {"$($logs[0])"} else {''}
  'Taille totale'         = [double]$logs[1]
  'Categorie recherchee'  = [double]$logs[2]
  'Pourcentage'           = [double]$logs[3]
  'Date de dernier acces' = [DateTime]$logs[5]
}
```